# Does bind actually require conversion to network byte order?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

In every top google result for "C Linux Socket Tutorial" ([1](https://linuxhint.com/posix-socket-with-c-programming/), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/), [3](https://linuxhint.com/posix-socket-with-c-programming/), [4](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-implement-tcp-sockets-in-c), [5](https://people.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Epxk/rutgers/notes/sockets/) ) they convert the port (and sometimes the address) to network byte order:

```c
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
```

Is this correct? Or does it just so happen to work since `port` is typically `0` and `INADDR_ANY` is also `0`, and therefore the conversion to network byte order does nothing.

Testing on my own linux machine, it seems that bind(...) expects host byte order as demonstrated in the following code.

```c
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
address.sin_port = htons(1);

int status = bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr\*)&address, sizeof(address));
if (status == -1)
{
    perror("bind");
    return 1;
}
```

I expect this to produce a permission error due to requesting a privileged port, however the program runs without error. And when I change `htons(1)` to just `1`, then the program fails with a permission error. Which seems to imply that `bind(...)` expects host byte order.

Am I misunderstanding something or are the majority of tutorials incorrect? Does `bind(...)` require host byte order or network byte order for the `sockaddr_in` struct?

Comment: The thing to understand is that many computers store integers in Little-Endian byte order (least-significant byte first), whereas network byte order is Big-Endian (most-significant byte first).

Comment: @RobertHarvey This does not answer the question at all. I understand little-endian and big-endian and I understand what network byte order is. I am asking if `bind()` requires host byte order or network byte order for its parameters. Several tutorials indicate that it requires network byte order. My own testing indicates otherwise. I am asking which is true.

Comment: Both `1` and `htons(1)` should give you a permission error as the former specifies port 256 (assuming little endian host ordering).

Comment: I wasn't attempting to answer the question.  If I was doing that, I would have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind requires a sockaddr. For IPv4 this means sockaddr_in. From [the documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

```
Address format
...
       struct sockaddr_in {
           sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
           in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
           struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
       };
```

So, it clearly says network byte order for `sin_port`.

> And when I change htons(1) to just 1, then the program fails with a permission error.

Since this is about a short (16 bit) a 1 in the wrong byte order just means 256. This is still below 1024 and thus requires root privileges to bind. Thus, no matter if you use `htons(1)` or `1` it should still fail with the same reason. I have no idea what exactly you did so it does not fail with `htons(1)` for you (for me it does).

Comment: Ah. I didn't think to read the comments on the the struct when going through the man pages. I looked at my code and I put `htonl(1)`, as opposed to `htons(1)`. Changing it to `htons(1)` yields an error. Thank you.

Comment: You should copy & paste code instead of typing something like the code you use to avoid such errors. @unlocking_locker